# Problem with mysql_query and inserting variable in it via sprintf()

Tags: mysql, sql, c

I'm trying to insert values of temperature readed from DS18B20 sensor in mysql database using sprintf to store variables in string and mysql_query to write them in database. In database i have two column "temp" and "date", which are int and string data types.

In my previous database all was working perfect, but in this i have some problems.

Default data in columns is NOT NULL

As the result i see temperature and date in terminal, but

```
SELECT * FROM tmpdate1
```

gives me "Empty set"

Please help me to find out where the problem is and solve it

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libfahw.h"
#include <mysql.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#define BUF_SIZE                    (64)

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        time_t t;
        char times[1024]={};
        char  timestr[] = {"%s"};
        time(&t);
        MYSQL *conn;
        char query[1024]={};
        char query1[1024]={};
        char query_str[] = {"INSERT INTO tmpdate1(temp) VALUES (%d)"};
        char query_str1[] = {"INSERT INTO tmpdate1(date) VALUES (%s)"};
        if ((conn=mysql_init(NULL))==NULL)
        {
           fprintf(stderr, "Could not init DB\n");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
       char temperature[BUF_SIZE];
       memset(temperature, 0, BUF_SIZE);

       if(mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "user12", "34klq*", "defense3", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "DB connection error\n");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
      for (int i = 1; i>0; i++)
 {
                printf("\n %d", atoi(temperature)/1000);
                printf("\n %s", ctime(&t));
                sprintf(times, timestr, ctime(&t));
                sprintf(query, query_str, atoi(temperature)/1000);
                sprintf(query1, query_str1, timestr);
                mysql_query(conn, query);
                mysql_query(conn, query1);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `INSERT`s? Do you really want the date and the corresponding temperature to be in different rows? And you might want to enclose the date literal with single quotes in the query.

Comment: What is mysql_query anyway?

Comment: I want to use two INSERT s because i need to do a line graph from database where y it's temperature and x it's date and time

Comment: Look up how to bind values to parameters in a query. What you're doing is very insecure and error prone and should be avoided.

Comment: So, is it a problem why i have blank columns?

Comment: Or my code has some specific issues?